# How to read a "queue" table from SQL Server using multiple threads

Tags: sql-server

Hi using SQL SERVER 2008 R2.

Say I have a table with a row of "Identifiers" and I want multiple "jobs/tasks/threads" from my application to read a chunck of Ids from this table.
How would one go about it?

So let's say we have a table of 12 rows and we have 3 jobs running any job can read an ordered sequence of 3 rows "maximum" on first come first server basis. Also we need to track were we stopped so the next set of rows get read by the next available job that will run.

Example

row 1 - thread 2

row 2 - thread 2

row 3 - thread 2

row 4 - thread 1 only picks 2 available rows at the time of execution.

row 5 - thread 1

row 6 - thread 3 only picks 2 available rows at the time of execution.

row 7 - thread 3

row 8 - to be processed by next available job

Rows will continue to stream in....

Comment: I think you need some readings about transaction management and isolation levels on SQL server

Comment: Have you considered using [SQL Server's Service Broker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx)?

Comment: Yeah don't like SSB to much. I rather my own solution. It's easier to control and maintain and manage the data as i see fit. SSB is too black boxish!

Comment: do you need to have all identifiers populated up front? what about a sequence table with an autonumber, and and stored procedure to insert a dummy record, then SCOPE_IDENTITY()  the new ID out. your threads can all run the get_sequence_num procedure in a loop, each pulling back a unique id.

Comment: In re: SSB, "oh… I know there's queuing built into the product, but I'd rather roll my own". Why not use it to just control the FIFO nature of what you're looking to do and still maintain the data in the table as you're doing now?

Comment: Hi. It's not so much that i dont want to write my own, but ssb is very black box solution. Plus I can write my own with a couple of stored procs. Plus I forgot to mention it's for push to external system. And also the ssb activator which no one knows about much of its voodoo magic either.